# Can a DPDT switch be used in reverse so that it selects 2 of 4 inputs to go to the 2 outputs?

Tags: switches

I mean title, but I’m trying to have it so that it will select 2 of the 4 inputs to connect to the 2 outputs.

Comment: Can you draw a circuit diagram showing how you think it should work?

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please can you edit your question and add a schematic of what you mean. The schematic tool here is a breeze to use, much better result than giant photos of hand sketches. Thanks and, again, welcome.

Comment: A DPDT switch has two channels of 2:1 selection. The answer is in your title, and repeated in your question, a DPDT selects two of the 4 terminals to connect to the two common terminals. What is it you don't understand? Perhaps drawing a schematic to put into your question would help us understand what you think needs answering.

Comment: A switch doesn't really have 'inputs' or 'outputs'. As such, there are different ways to use it, and there is no 'reverse' way because there is no 'correct' way.

Answer (score 2):

There are not really "inputs" and "outputs" on a switch, but if you arbitrarily call the contacts "inputs" as shown below you have situation shown:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBHBik.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you need to independently select 1 or 2 vs. 3 or 4 then there are 4 combinations and you can use 2 SPDT switches.

If you want be able to select any of the 4 inputs to either of the 2 outputs there are 8 possibilities and you'd probably end up using a multipole rotary switch.

Answer (score 0):

The DPDT switch lacks independence flipping of the toggle_mechanics, thus you will always have coordinated selection.

If you want such as '1 and 3' or '2 and 4', always, then answer is yes.